# Automorphism group of a finite group

Tags: finite-groups, automorphism-group

For which finite groups $G$ is $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ isomorphic to a (non necessarily strict) subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Do you known any interesting examples?

Comment: $Aut(C_{2})$ is trivial, $Aut(S_{3})\cong S_{3}$.